# How do I convert a WrappedArray column in spark dataframe to Strings?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to convert a column which contains Array[String] to String, but I consistently get this error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 78.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 78.0 (TID 1691, ip-******): java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

Here's the piece of code

```
val mkString = udf((arrayCol:Array[String])=>arrayCol.mkString(","))  
val dfWithString=df.select($"arrayCol").withColumn("arrayString",
      mkString($"arrayCol"))
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`WrappedArray` is not an `Array` (which is plain old Java `Array` not a natve Scala collection). You can either change signature to:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

(arrayCol: WrappedArray[String]) => arrayCol.mkString(",")
```

or use one of the supertypes like `Seq`:

```
(arrayCol: Seq[String]) => arrayCol.mkString(",")
```

In the recent Spark versions you can use `concat_ws` instead:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat_ws

df.select(concat_ws(",", $"arrayCol"))
```

Comment: I tried to use WrappedArray but that type wasnt recognized. Seq works fine

Answer (score 2):

The code work for me:

```
df.select("wifi_ids").rdd.map(row =>row.get(0).asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[WrappedArray[String]]].toSeq.map(x=>x.toSeq.apply(0)))
```

In your case,I guess it is:

```
val mkString = udf(arrayCol=>arrayCol.asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[String]].toArray.mkString(","))  
val dfWithString=df.select($"arrayCol").withColumn("arrayString",mkString($"arrayCol"))
```