# spark dataframe udf mapping indices to values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, indexing, udf

I have a spark data frame where one column consists of indices of a list. I would like to write a udf that allows me to create a new column with the values associated with the indices.

E.g.

Suppose I have the following dataframe and array:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((0, Array(1, 1, 2)), (1, Array(1, 2, 0))))
df.show()
+---+---------+
| _1|       _2|
+---+---------+
|  0|[1, 1, 2]|
|  1|[1, 2, 0]|
+---+---------+
val sArray = Array("a", "b", "c")
```

I would like to be able to map the indicies in `_2` to their values in `sArray` leading to this:

```
+---+---------+---------+
| _1|       _2|       _3|
+---+---------+---------+
|  0|[1, 1, 2]|[b, b, c]|
|  1|[1, 2, 0]|[b, c, a]|
+---+---------+---------+
```

I have been trying to do this with a udf:

```
def indexer (values: Array[String]) = 
  udf((indices: Array[Int]) => indices.map(values(_)))
df.withColumn("_3", indexer(sArray)($"_2"))
```

However when I do this, I get the following error:

> Failed to execute user defined function
>
> ... Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [I

What is going wrong here? How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a WrappedArray column in spark dataframe to Strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539068/how-do-i-convert-a-wrappedarray-column-in-spark-dataframe-to-strings)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When operating on an `ArrayType` column in a DataFrame, the actual type passed into a UDF is `mutable.WrappedArray`. The failure you see is the result of trying to cast this `WrappedArray` into the `Array[Int]` your function expects.

The fix is rather simple - define the function to expect a `mutable.WrappedArray[Int]`:

```
def indexer (values: Array[String]): UserDefinedFunction = {
  udf((indices: mutable.WrappedArray[Int]) => indices.map(values(_)))
}
```